# Can i get cloudfront-view-country request in my wordpress for Geo targeting?

Tags: wordpress, lambda, amazon-cloudfront, request-headers, ip-geolocation

I need Geo information from each users who visit my website in wordpress, in order to present correct current. After I use cloudfront, the WC_Geolocation doesn't work. I was thinking picking cloudfront-view-country header from cloudfront request to my server. The below two method I have test, but didn't get what i expected.

1. Add the cloudfront-view-country to Whitelist Headers. Use getallheaders() to read the request headers in the wordpress in functions.php, but didn't find the expected header cloudfront-view-country.
   [image: Whitelist Headers]
   snippet in the functions.php

> ```
> $headers =  getallheaders();
>
> foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
> echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>'
> }
> ```

2. I use lambda + API gateway, pass CloudFront-Viewer-Country to lambda in Body Mapping Templates

> ```
> detect_countryCode": "$input.params('CloudFront-Viewer-Country')
>
> catch the countryCode with event in lambda
>
> exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
>
>   let countryCode = event.detect_countryCode;
>
>   callback(null, countryCode)
> };
> ```

When I test with API in a browser, it did show the right country code. However, after I use `wp_remote_get()` to integrated this API in wordpress. It always shows "US" which is my server's locationi. I believe the logic is wrong in the second method. It is my server invoke the API, of course it will return the country code of my server which is in "US".

Any comments would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution in the end? looking to implement this functionality on my site